# Create extension with multiple submodules

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I'd like to create an extension (module) that includes a modification of the base system, and also includes two separate modules that can be placed in layouts. Both of these single instance modules depend on this modification.

With multi instance modules you can create multiple instances of a module who all share the same controllers and views.

Is there a way to have one base module install other modules that are then inserted as children of said base module, share the same admin controller / model, but different catalog controller / views?

Uninstalling the base module should lead to uninstalling the child modules as well.

Comment: The best way to understand how... Just copy all files for example of the "HTML Content" module. You must find all `html.php` files and html.twig files in `admin` and `catalog` directories. duplicate them and rename to you module name. Then find all instances in files which contain `html` and change accordinally to your file name. so you have duplicated html module. That let you  understand how to create your own module in OC which will have submodules... Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating Model, View, Controller and Language files for the installable module. Let's call it the `Main module`.

Then you can create models, controllers and views for the `sub-modules` and load them into the Main Controller.

Example:

```php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMainModule extends Controller {
    public function install() {
        $this->load->model('extension/module/MainModule');

        /**
         * Load submodule's model into the Main's module controller
         */
        $this->load->model('extension/module/SubModule');


        $this->model_extension_module_MainModule->install();

        /**
         * Execute install function that exists in Submodel (submodule)
         */
        $this->model_extension_module_SubModule->install();
    }
}
```

Using this approach you can create many "sub-modules" and install or uninstall them all together at the same time.

Note: Try to organize your classes and functions or else you will create an untangleable mess. Also keep always in mind the "Single Responsibility" principle.